# Use git changes from another branch

Tags: git

Is there a way to pull in a project from another branch so that my intelisense can see classes from that branch without modifying my current branch? I don't want to merge because the classes should be separated, I just want to pull in the changes without committing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest thing to do is to merge the branch without committing.

```
git merge --no-commit thatotherbranch
```

Then when you're done, throw out the changes.

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

---

If you want to do come experiments, you can create a temporary branch and merge things into it. Then delete it when you're done (or decide it's a good idea and keep it).

```
# Checkout the branch you want to work on
git checkout mybranch

# Create a new branch and check it out
git checkout -b tempbranch

# Merge in the branch with the changes you want
git merge thatotherbranch

...do whatever you like...

# Switch back to the original branch
git checkout mybranch

# Delete the temp branch
git branch -d tempbranch
```

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the merge without committing the results.

Step 1: Check out the branch you want to merge INTO (I'll be using master for this example)

```
git checkout master
```

Step 2: Merge your previous branch into master with the --no-commit tag

```
git merge YOUR_BRANCH_NAME --no-commit
```

That should be sufficient. You can always run a diff at this point or before merging if you'd like to check the changes in advance.

The merge --ff tag may also be useful to you, but I've yet to use it so can't comment for certain.

> When the merge resolves as a fast-forward, only update the branch pointer, without creating a merge commit. This is the default behavior.

```
git merge YOUR_BRANCH_NAME --no-commit --ff
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---no-commit

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff